# Office.js How to insert 2 content controls, one at start of selection and one at end of selection

Tags: javascript, office-js, word-2016

In word 2016, when a user selects some text they have an option to place a starting and ending content control at the start and end of a selection. Is there any good way to do this? Whenever I try to insert a content control, it replaces the selected text.

this is what i have:

```
const ContentControlRange = context.document.getSelection();
const myContentControl = ContentControlRange.insertContentControl();

//set content control properties here

return context.sync().then(function () {
    console.log("creating cc context.sync()");

    //do other stuff
});
```

and if i call this function twice the last content control just replaces the first content control. Any help appreciated thanks.

I tried:

```
const ContentControlRange = context.document.getSelection().getRange('After');
```

but i keep getting an 'Invalid Argument' error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following Script Lab code snippet works for me. It uses *three* `Ranges`, although theoretically two would be sufficient. In any case, the original `Range` (the selection) needs to be retained so that it's possible to first get the position before the selection, then the position after the selection.

This code uses `"Start"` and `"End"` as position parameters. If these are not used the content control(s) will replace the selection, same as if you select text then type.

```
async function
    insertTwoCC() {
    await Word.run(async(context) => {

        let currSel = context.document.getSelection();
        let rngBefore = currSel.getRange("Start");
        let rngAfter = currSel.getRange("End");
        let ccBefore = rngBefore.insertContentControl();
        let ccAfter = rngAfter.insertContentControl();
        await context.sync();
        })
    }
```

Comment: Changed my code to use getRange start and end but i am still getting the same error. It seems the error source is the return context.sync(). whenever i use the getRange method to insert content controls the error occurs.

Comment: It worked fine for me @ArnNun. Have you checked whether the version of Word you're working with meets the requirement set for the `getRange` method? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/office/requirement-sets/word-api-requirement-sets?view=office-js

Comment: Aha! that was it. at work we are using the 16.0.4266.1001. version. This version only contains the WordApi 1.1 requirement set according to here: [Word JavaScript API requirement sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/office/requirement-sets/word-api-requirement-sets?view=office-js)